# docker-compose command 'npm start' does not start react app automatically?

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am reasonably new to react application.

docker-compose command 'npm start' does not start react app automatically?

package.json:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
    "eslintConfig": {
```

docker-compose:

```
.....:

  command: bash -c "npm start && nginx -g 'daemon off;' "
```

Log Output:

```
portals_1            | 
portals_1            | > myreact@0.1.0 start /~/~/myreact
portals_1            | > react-scripts start
portals_1            | 
portals_1            | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.0.9/
portals_1            | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
portals_1            | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /~/~/myreact/public
portals_1            | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
portals_1            | Starting the development server...
portals_1            |
```

At this point, docker container runs but react server does not.
However if I bash into docker container

```
docker-compose exec portals bash
```

I check that port 3000 is still free. If I go to the directory and run `npm start` then react runs normally and everything is as expected.

Log Output: -
    You can now view myreact in the browser.

```
Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://172.18.0.9:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.......
```

Why react application is not able to start normally from docker-compose?

Comment: did you found an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the issue is that `stdin` closes when you run `npm start`.

#### Solution 1

Add `stdin_open: true` to `docker-compose.yml`

#### Solution 2

Add the following to your `Dockerfile`

```
 ENV CI=true
```